# Toggle HtmlEncode on asp:BoundField

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Title is pretty self explanatory. I have two bound fields and I want to toggle them with a function (either js or c#). But I'm not sure how since they do not have ID elements.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="FieldOldValue" HeaderText="FieldOldValue" HtmlEncode="false"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="FieldNewValue" HeaderText="FieldNewValue" HtmlEncode="false"/>

<label class="switch">
  <input id="htmlToggle" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleHTML()">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Ideally the JS would look something like this:

```
function toggleHTML() {
  if('htmlToggle'.checked) //render HTML (HtmlEncode="false")
  else //un-render HTML (HtmlEncode="true")
}
```

The fields would be showing raw html initially, and when you hit the toggle, both fields will render the html.

UPDATE: I have maybe gotten closer to solving this but still not actually getting it to work (I'm trying either asp:Button or toggle). Here is some more code:

Currently trying with a button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" text="Swap" ID="htmlToggle2" class="btn" OnClick="SwapHTML"/>
```

C#:

```
protected void SwapHTML(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((BoundField)GridView2.Columns[2]).HtmlEncode.Equals(false))
            {
                ((BoundField)GridView2.Columns[2]).HtmlEncode = true;
                ((BoundField)GridView2.Columns[3]).HtmlEncode = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ((BoundField)GridView2.Columns[2]).HtmlEncode = false;
                ((BoundField)GridView2.Columns[3]).HtmlEncode = false;
            }
        }
```